# How can I disable Replays in PES 2011?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2011

I want to disable all replays in Pro Evolution Soccer 2011. I looked over the settings but couldn't find anything related. How can I disable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to disable the replays on Xbox 360. It was a criticism point on PES 2011 with slightly changed behaviour in PES 2012.

Apparently there is a patch for disabling automatic replays on the PC Version: [PES 2011 replay disabler](http://www.pes-patch.com/2011/08/pes-2011-replay-disabler-v1-3-beta-by-cabry.html)